# Обновление записи в БД Yii2

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2

Вообщем прошу помощи уже всю голову сломал никак не могу обновить запись в бд. Вот код контроллера:

```
public function actionEdit($id) {
    $model = Pages::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $model->isNewRecord = false;
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(array('/admin/pages'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('edit', compact('model'));
}
```

Вот код html:

```
<div class="row">
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'title'); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'meta_keywords'); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'meta_description'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'description')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'editorOptions' => ElFinder::ckeditorOptions('elfinder',[]),
    ]);
    ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <?= Html::submitButton('Редактировать страницу', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Вообщем старые данные выводятся я их изменяю жму кнопку он меня кидает на страницу как при удачном изменении, но ни каких изменений нет.

Comment: $model = Pages::findOne($id) попробуйте так.

Comment: а если `$model = Pages::findOne($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&&$model->validate()) {
        $model->save(false);` ?

Comment: нет, к сожалению не робит((

Comment: Используй дебаг-панель, посмотри что попадает в post, какие значения атрибутов у модели после `$model->load()`, что сохраняет yii в базу, и убери строчку `$model->isNewRecord = false;`(зачем она?)

Comment: @pa3py6aka ну дебаг-панель говорит, что все данные что я записал висят в post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем я нашел ответ на свой вопрос правда он не самый элегантный, вот код вдруг пригодится:

```
public function actionEdit($id) {
    $model = Pages::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $model->title = $_POST['Pages']['title'];
        $model->meta_keywords = $_POST['Pages']['meta_keywords'];
        $model->meta_description = $_POST['Pages']['meta_description'];
        $model->description = $_POST['Pages']['description'];
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(array('/admin/pages'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('edit', compact('model'));
}
```

Я чесно говоря хз почему yii2 все приходящие данные заворачивает еще в один массив, в моём случае это "Pages", хотя скорее всего он просто берет название модели.

Comment: Вообще метод `$model->load()` автоматически берёт данные из этого массива с названием формы. Вообще я думаю у вас в модели `Pages` в методе `rules` отсутствуют значения для этих данных - `title, meta_keywords` и т.д.

Comment: @pa3py6aka может оно и так, но если бы все было гуд я бы сюда явно не написал бы

Comment: так у вас в модели `Pages` в rules прописаны эти атрибуты?

Comment: да они были прописаны

Answer (score 0):

Я более чем уверен, что ваши данные не прошли валидацию.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'errors' => $model->errors()
        ]);
    }
}
```

И во вьюшке вывести например, так:

```
echo "<PRE>";
var_dump($errors);
echo "</PRE>";
?>
```

Это покажет, какие данные были неверно введены. 
Ваш способ сохранения исключает валидацию вообще, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: Ну я вообще чтобы больше не париться с таким гемороем, решил создавать модели через генератор дописывая все что нужно после, и теперь никаких ошибок не лезет кстати валидация у меня норм прорабатывает.